# xpages tag cloud: links are missing

Tags: xpages, tag-cloud

I'm tryng to use the tag cloud control from Ext.Library 9.0.1 (20160428). The cloud is generated with the correct values form the category view but all the links are missing.

I suspect I'm missing something stupid and my question will look a little bit silly but... I've already lost some hours on this without getting any result.

This is the code for the tagcloud:

```
    <xe:tagCloud id="tagCloud1" sliderVisible="true">
    <xe:this.cloudData>
    <xe:dominoViewCloudData categoryColumn="0" viewName="indice"LinkTargetPage="/risultati.xsp" linkRequestParam="nometag">
   </xe:dominoViewCloudData>
   </xe:this.cloudData>
   </xe:tagCloud>
```

This is what I get in a browser (just an example, all the lines look similar):

```
<li style="display:inline">
<a role="link" title="11 Entries" class="tagCloudSize9">Miscellaneous</a>
</li>
```

As you can see there is no link to anything, so the user can't click the cloud label.

Any advice will be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: `LinkTargetPage=` with capital letter is just a typo? It has to be `linkTargetPage=`

Comment: yes, sorry . It was a typo

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was only a cache-related trouble. I've restarted my server and it started to work as expected.
Just wondering why and how to avoid in the future...